# Unable to generate sequence of dates by quarter properly in R

Tags: r, date, seq

I would like to generate a sequence of dates by quarter backwards from a given date (31 July 2015). Instead of getting the last day of April, I get the first day of May as below:

```
> seq(as.Date('2015-07-31'), as.Date('2014-09-30'), by = '-3 month')
[1] "2015-07-31" "2015-05-01" "2015-01-31" "2014-10-31"
```

I also tried passing `-quarter` in the `by` option but I got the following error:

```
> seq(as.Date('2015-07-31'), as.Date('2014-09-30'), by = '-quarter')
Error in seq.Date(as.Date("2015-07-31"), as.Date("2014-09-30"), by = "-quarter") : 
invalid string for 'by'
```

While I can check the day of the month and correct accordingly should the dates have been over-adjusted into the wrong month, I was wondering if there exists a parsimonious snippet of code to do the above?

Comment: What is your desired output from the operation above?

Comment: @DavidArenburg [1] "2015-07-31" "2015-04-31" "2015-01-31" "2014-10-31"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix would be to take the first day of the following month and substract one:

```
seq(as.Date('2015-08-01'), as.Date('2014-10-01'), by = '-3 month') -1 

[1] "2015-07-31" "2015-04-30" "2015-01-31" "2014-10-31"
```